# Get specified url part in policy with Azure APIM Policy

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Is it possible to, within policy, get the specified url part below:

[image]

```
<policies>
        <inbound>
            <base />    
        </inbound>
        <backend>
            <base />
        </backend>
        <outbound>
            <base />
            <find-and-replace from="https://thirdparty/certs" 
                 to="@(specified url part)" />        
        </outbound>
        <on-error>
            <base />
        </on-error>
    </policies>
```

Please note that the whole url might include versioning and prefix.

Answer (score 11):

The whole URI (let's assume https://contoso.com/myapi/.wellknown/openid-config) is comprised of:

1. Scheme: `context.Request.OriginalUrl.Scheme`
2. Host: `context.Request.OriginalUrl.Host`
3. Optional port: `context.Request.OriginalUrl.Port`
4. API suffix: `context.Api.Path`
5. Operation path: the rest of it

So operation part of URL can be calculated by something close to: `context.Request.OriginalUrl.Path.Trim('/').Substring(context.Api.Path.Trim('/').Length)`

Comment: context.Api is null for me. Is it because it requires API published? Is there an alternative?

Comment: That should only happen if API was not identified for a request, such calls usually result in 404. Are you sure you're making correct test call? Will you get a proper response if you remove this policy?

Comment: yes, it works without the policy. But context.Api is null when it is added.

Answer (score 0):

Example of a policy expression, that when used in the inbound path can be used to redirect an incoming request based on version information included as a query parameter in a published API.

```html
<choose>
    <when condition="@(context.Request.Url.Query.GetValueOrDefault("version") == "2014-03")">
      <set-backend-service base-url="http://contoso.com/api/1.6/" />
    </when>
    <otherwise>
      <set-backend-service base-url="http://contoso.com/api/2.0/"
    </otherwise>
  </choose>
```

Find more details at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/policy-expressions-in-azure-api-management/

Comment: Thanks for your info. But it is not the answer, as I am looking for the specified url part mentioned on the opening post.

I knew the url provided on your post, which has no info on my question.